# Azure Devops construct variable from map parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The [Azure Devops template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) I am working on I want to construct a variable from input parameter named `terraformVars`:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: terraformVars
    type: object
    default: {}

variables:
  - name: terraformVariableString
    value: "-val var.key=var.value ${{ each var in terraformVars }}"
```

By default the string is empty, but when the pipeline passes values:

```yaml
...
extends:
  template: ../templates/terraform-pipeline.yml
  parameters:
    terraformVars:
      client_id: abcdef
      client_secret: ghijkl
```

the `terraformVariableString` will be `-var "client_id=abcdef" -var "client_secret=ghijkl"`

Comment: Hi Joost, any update on this question, have you checked the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using is wrong, there is no such way of using expression. Note the use of Directives and the use of compile-time parameters, do not confuse the two.

Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression.

The general way is this:

***give_parameter.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

parameters:
  - name: terraformVars
    type: object
    default: 
      client_id: abcdef
      client_secret: ghijkl

extends:
  template: parameter_template.yml
  parameters:
      terraformVars: ${{parameters.terraformVars}}
```

***using_parameter.yml***

```
parameters:
  - name: terraformVars
    type: object
    default: {}

variables:
  - name: terraformVariableString
    value: ${{ parameters.terraformVars.client_id}}

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host $(terraformVariableString)
```